# Invalid number of arguments to Solidity function

Tags: solidity, truffle, truffle-test

I have a function in my contract. First takes argument, the second one does not. Everything works fine until I change the name of the second one into the same one as the first one and create overloading. Then during tests execution I am getting

> Error: Invalid number of arguments to Solidity function

What might be wrong?

Comment: The problem is with `claim` function: https://github.com/pw94/zeppelin-solidity/blob/ff834f7ca54f81a3257a5dde765d789cae4ea593/contracts/payment/SplitPayment.sol

Comment: And here are the tests: https://github.com/pw94/zeppelin-solidity/blob/ff834f7ca54f81a3257a5dde765d789cae4ea593/test/payment/SplitPayment.test.js